# validate_conversion does not compile in package but as standalone procedure

Tags: plsql

I'm getting an compilation error, when I try to use validate_conversion in plsql.

```
Error: PLS-00801: Interner Fehler [*** ASSERT at file pdz2.c, line 5361; The_Exp is null.; TEST__DBNAME__B__2920081[10, 3]]
Line: 10
Text: END;
```

Funny thing is, this error only occurs if compiled in a package. An MWE is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE test IS
  PROCEDURE my_VALIDATE_CONVERSION(asNbr VARCHAR2);
END test;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY test IS
  PROCEDURE my_VALIDATE_CONVERSION(asNbr VARCHAR2) IS
  BEGIN
    CASE VALIDATE_CONVERSION(asNbr AS NUMBER, '999999D99', ' NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '',.''')
      WHEN 1 THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('He');
      ELSE
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Cu');
    END CASE;
  END;
BEGIN
  NULL;
END test;
/
```

If compiled as standalone procedure `my_VALIDATE_CONVERSION` it works just fine.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE my_VALIDATE_CONVERSION(asNbr VARCHAR2) IS
BEGIN
  CASE VALIDATE_CONVERSION(asNbr AS NUMBER, '999999D99', ' NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '',.''')
    WHEN 1 THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('He');
    ELSE
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Cu');
  END CASE;
END;
```

What's going on here?

Im using:

- PL/SQL Developer Version 13.0.6.1911  (64 bit)
- Oracle Database 18c Standard Edition 2 Release 18.0.0.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a bug in the database.  I would try upgrading to Oracle 19c or apply the latest patch set to your database. I was able to compile your package in my database (version 19.6.0.0.0) without any errors.

Answer (score 0):

This internal failure for sure will happen with the procedure compilation. The fact that it did not suggests that the compilation of the package was done with PLSQL_DEBUG turned on, and the compilation of the procedure was done without.

Answer (score 0):

When you use this function in package  in
`Select Validate_Conversion(String AS Number) Into variable From Dual`, is compiled successful.

```
Select Validate_Conversion(p_Oran AS Number) Into IsNumeric From dual; --COMPILED
IsNumeric := Validate_Conversion(p_Oran AS Number); --FAILURE
If Validate_conversion(p_Oran AS Number) = 0 Then  --FAILURE
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/auxJU.png)